# Why did the spirit kiss the guy in "Asylum"?

Tags: supernatural

In *Supernatural* season 1 episode 10 "Asylum" we see an asylum haunted by the spirits of those who'd be inhumanly treated/experimented upon there.

The civilian couple that got mixed up in the action get separated for a bit. The guy sees a spirit and assumes it's his girlfriend. The spirit then proceeds to walk up and kiss him. He kisses her back for a few seconds and then realizes it's not his girlfriend but rather a creepy looking spirit, and runs off.

We later learn that the spirits are actually

> not trying to hurt them, they're trying to whisper a room # in their ears to lead the Winchesters to the evil doctor who experimented on them.

But that still doesn't explain why the spirit would just initiate kissing a stranger. Do we know why?

Answer (score 2):

In watching the scene in question it looks more like the spirit was trying to pull his head into a position where it could whisper in his ear and he actually initiated the kissing as to why the spirit went with it its possible it enjoyed being kissed or its possible it was waiting for an opening to whisper its message